# Download file from Parse throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

In my application i can successfully upload file to parse.com. But when I tried to download it, it is giving null pointer exception.Here is my code to download file.

```
ParseObject downloadData = new ParseObject("DownloadData");
        ParseFile downloadFile = (ParseFile) downloadData.get("File");
        downloadFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    String x= new String(bytes);
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity2.this)
                            .setTitle("Downloaded File")
                            .setMessage(x)
                            .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity2.this)
                            .setTitle("Download File")
                            .setMessage("An Error Occurred")
                            .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
```

the official documentation is confusing. Can anyone tell me a way to fix this.

Comment: Where is it giving you a NPE?

Comment: In the Second line `ParseFile downloadFile = (ParseFile) downloadData.get("File");`

Comment: please dump the exception stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call `get()` on ParseObject created like this. 
First you need to call parseQuery on your Parse Class and get this ParseObject from this query result.Now call get() on this ParseObject.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("DownloadData");
query.getInBackground("parse_object_id", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
public void done(ParseObject downloadData, ParseException e) {
if (e == null) {
  // This object will contain your file
   ParseFile downloadFile = (ParseFile) downloadData.get("File");
    downloadFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                String x= new String(bytes);
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity2.this)
                        .setTitle("Downloaded File")
                        .setMessage(x)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                        .show();
            } else {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity2.this)
                        .setTitle("Download File")
                        .setMessage("An Error Occurred")
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });
 } else {
  // something went wrong
  }

});
```